# mysql returns wrong results when using "like"

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Yeah like title says, you will think of utf8 set names problems .. maybe it's even true.

I have this query:

```
select distinct ort from veranstaltungsorte where ort like 'ka%';
```

And although it starts with "ka" I get "Köln" as a result. Together with 3 correct cities.

When I use

```
select distinct ort from veranstaltungsorte where ort like 'kö%';
```

Everything's right; it's just that my db thinks, Köln also start with "ka" ?!

I was trying character sets and so on but none of them worked .. any ideas ?

Comment: a) Please post the result of `DESCRIBE veranstaltungsorte;` to give us a glimpse on how your table is set up, b) make sure you query the table using utf8 (or whatever character set you're using), too.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_general_ci` will sort `Ö` with `O`

So maybe that's what you want.

More about this [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748)

otherwise. when you want to search specific on characters like ÄËÖ you can set it to `utf8_swedish_ci` that will work with `ö`

Answer (score 0):

It was not utf8_general_ci I already tried it before .. it's rather this one:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
CHANGE ort ort VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

Important note: "like" will now act case-sensitive .. so I capitalize the first letter and I am done.
Nevertheless thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data you are actually storing in the `ort` column is incorrectly encoded: `Köln` is actually stored as `KÃ¶ln`. That would explain why you get a match when looking for `ka`: as far as the current collation is considered, `KÃ = ka`.

The fact that you haven't noticed this before means you actually have two problems:

1. The data you have in the database *right now* is broken. You can check this with any database tool.
2. You are using the incorrect encoding to connect to the database: you are sending strings encoded in UTF-8 while the connection is set to latin1 or something similar.

The fact that the same character mangling happens both when you read and write means that you may not notice any problems when using your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem with these accented characters causing `LIKE` to return incorrect results. For me, changing the collation was not an option. I found that [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) works great as an alternative, and in fact has been performing much better than `LIKE`.

For example, in your case,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ort FROM veranstaltungsorte WHERE ort LIKE 'ka%';
```

becomes

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ort FROM veranstaltungsorte WHERE ort REGEXP '^ka';
```